# How to create a BMI calculator using event handlers

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

I am relatively new to aspx and was assigned a small task to create a BMI calculator. This calculator requires two forms within one page (one for metric use and one for imperial/standard feet, inches, and pounds. I have the two forms functioning fine using small event handlers, but I am completely lost when it comes to making an event handler for the "calculate" and "clear" button. For the first portion of the task I need to have an individual event handler for each button. I know there is a way to use a single event handler, but I am not allowed to do that at this time!

Code that I have currently written. To save some time, I'll just post one of the forms, the imperial/standard one. Sorry if it is messy:

```
<form id="US" runat="server" visible="true">
   <div style="background-color:#4DB8FF; width:350px; height:300px; margin:auto; text-align:center;">
        <h4>
            Body Mass Index Calculator 
            <asp:Button id="btnUS" runat="server" text="US" OnClick="btnUS_Click" /> 
            <asp:Button id="btnMetric" runat="server" Text="Metric" OnClick="btnMetric_Click" /> <br />

            <script runat="server">
                protected void btnUS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    this.US.Visible = true;
                    this.Metric.Visible = false;
                }

                protected void btnMetric_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    this.US.Visible = false;
                    this.Metric.Visible = true;
                }

            </script>
        </h4>


                  <asp:label ID="lbl1" Text="Height:" runat="server" />
                     <asp:TextBox ID="heightus" runat="server" />feet<br />
                     <asp:TextBox ID="heightus1" runat="server" />inch(es)<br />
                  <asp:Label ID="lbl2" Text="Weight:" runat="server" />
                     <asp:TextBox ID="weightus" runat="server" />lbs<br />
                <br />
                     <asp:Button ID="calcUS" Text="Calculate" runat="server" />
                     <asp:Button ID="clearUS" Text="Clear" runat="server"/> 
                <br /><br />
                  <asp:Label ID="lbl3" Text="Results:" runat="server" />
                     <asp:TextBox ID="resultus" runat="server" /> <br />


    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, there are three(3) text boxes which hold the information for the calculation. The Feet, Inch(es), and Lbs text box. I need to gather the information that is placed in those boxes and use it to calculate the individuals BMI.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I'd do:
  id="US" runat="server" visible="true">
  
   
        
            Body Mass Index Calculator

```
        <script runat="server">
            protected void btnUS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.US.Visible = true;
                this.Metric.Visible = false;
            }

            protected void btnMetric_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.US.Visible = false;
                this.Metric.Visible = true;
            }
             protected void calcUS_Click()
        {
              //do the computation here
              resultus.text = //put the results here
        }
        </script>
    </h4>


              <asp:label ID="lbl1" Text="Height:" runat="server" />
                 <asp:TextBox ID="heightus" runat="server" />feet<br />
                 <asp:TextBox ID="heightus1" runat="server" />inch(es)<br />
              <asp:Label ID="lbl2" Text="Weight:" runat="server" />
                 <asp:TextBox ID="weightus" runat="server" />lbs<br />
            <br />
                 <asp:Button ID="calcUS" Text="Calculate" runat="server" 
    onclick="calcUS_Click" />
                 <asp:Button ID="clearUS" Text="Clear" runat="server"/> 
            <br /><br />
              <asp:Label ID="lbl3" Text="Results:" runat="server" />
                 <asp:TextBox ID="resultus" runat="server" /> <br />


</div>
```

Comment: Great thanks! as for the computation, how do I go about writing it so that it works with the regular BMI formula of (Weight(lbs) / (height in inches * height in inches)) *703? I recognize that I will need to convert the feet to inches, but I'm not sure how to write that code.

Comment: You might want to do something like this: protected void protected void  calcUS_Click()
        {

              resultus.text = (weightus.text / (heightus.text * heightus1.text)) * 703;
        }

Comment: EDIT: You might want to do something like this: protected void protected void  calcUS_Click()
        {
//This will convert the feet to inches (formula is: feet / 12)
              resultus.text = (weightus.text / (( heightus.text / 12) * (heightus1.text / 12))) * 703;
        }